# Assigning related field value from List to a object in a Apex Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

I am making a simple trigger that is updating a field value based on the name of a record through a lookup field. Im struggling getting the ParentRecord.Name value assigned to the FSL__GantLabel__c. Any help would be greatly appreciated -- Here is the code:

```
trigger ServiceAppointmentTrigger on ServiceAppointment (after insert) {
    List<ServiceAppointment> saList = [SELECT Id, ParentRecord.Name 
                                       FROM ServiceAppointment 
                                       WHERE Id IN :Trigger.New 
                                       AND ParentRecordType = 'WorkOrder'];
    
   List<ServiceAppointment> saToUpdate = new List<ServiceAppointment>();
    
    for(ServiceAppointment sa : saList) {
        if(saList.size() > 0) {
            sa.FSL__GanttLabel__c = saList.get(ParentRecord.Name);
            saToUpdate.add(sa);
            
        }
        
        
    }
    
    if(saToUpdate.size() > 0) {
        update satoUpdate;
    }
        
}
```

Comment: This code should be giving you an error when you try to save it. Generally speaking, if you're getting an error, you should include it (the full text of the error + the stack trace. Don't try to paraprase it) in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your trigger has some issues with syntax, and some things that serve no purpose.

```java
    List<ServiceAppointment> saToUpdate = new List<ServiceAppointment>();
    
    for(ServiceAppointment sa : saList) {
        // If saList is empty, you wouldn't reach this if() statement
        //   because we only enter loops when there are records to loop over
        if(saList.size() > 0) {
            // saList is a List
            // the .get() method is primarily used on maps, not lists
            // At any rate, this isn't how you access related data
            sa.FSL__GanttLabel__c = saList.get(ParentRecord.Name);
            saToUpdate.add(sa);
        }
    }

    // This check is not necessary.
    // If you perform DML on an empty list, Salesforce is smart enough to not
    //   actually try to perform the DML
    if(saToUpdate.size() > 0) {
        update satoUpdate;
    }
```

I suspect you're getting an error on the `sa.FSL__GanttLabel__c = saList.get(ParentRecord.Name);` line.

To access related data (once you've queried it), you simply use dot-notation like you would for any other field. If you're working with a custom relationship field (which ends in `__c`), you'd need to change that to `__r` in your query and when you access the data using dot-notation.

That problematic line should simply be `sa.FSL__GanttLabel__c = sa.ParentRecord.Name;`, assuming that `ParentRecord` is a standard relationship field.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Your map is by `Id`. If you break it out into two steps it might be easier to understand.

```
ServiceAppointment record = saList.get(sa.Id);
String label = record.ParentRecord.Name;
```